# Manipulating selected text in React Native TextInput component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, textinput

I'd like to know how to manipulate *selected* text that is inside of a TextInput component.

An easy example of this would be making a rich-text editor; when the user has selected text and clicked on a button (say, the "Bold" button), then I'd want to run a bolding function on that selected text.

I know the TextInput has a `onSelectionChange` prop that I'm going to have to use at some point (when the user taps a button), but how would that work exactly?

Comment: Are you sure a TextInput supports formatted text? I don't think so. What you can do is add bbcode-style formatting to the text and have a formatted preview elsewhere. Basically, a button tap turns `some text here` into `some [b]text[/b] here` inside the TextInput, and a preview shows "some **text** here".

Comment: Yeah, good call. That'd be totally okay with me, I'm just not sure how to actually call a function that would place that stuff around the selected text. Any tips? Thanks so much!

Comment: Use [`selection`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selection) to read the string indices, then use basic text replacement.

Comment: @ChrisG TextInput *does* support rich text. Right now I'm experiencing an issue where copying from web to TextInput preserves formatting. It's driving me insane. For what it's worth, you can format text by specifying child components with styles: `<TextInput>This sentence has <Text style={{color:'red'}}>red</Text> text.</TextInput>`